# Set date field to null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, vbscript, asp-classic

I am trying to set a date field to null in a MS SQL Server 2005 database.

I am using VBScript on asp pages.

The column in the DB allows for nulls. But when I try to add a record and not pass anything along to the date field, or try to set the field back to Null, I get this error:

> Provider error '80020005'
>
> Type mismatch.
>
> /add_client_notes.asp, line 142

Line 142 is: `rs("client_notes_duedate") = client_notes_duedate`

Here is all the code:

```
<% 
    clientnotes_id = request("clientnotes_id")
    client_notes_duedate = request("client_notes_duedate")
    if client_notes_duedate = "" then
        client_notes_duedate = Null
    end if

    openSQL("SELECT * FROM client_notes WHERE client_notes_id=" & clientnotes_id)
    rs("client_notes_duedate") = client_notes_duedate
    rs.update

%>
```

I have tried sending an empty value and a NULL value but both return the same error.

When I send the date value along it works great.

How can I set client_notes_duedate back to NULL?

Comment: Wow, sorry guys, but I just found my real problem. The ajax function I was using to post to this script was pointing to an older asp file, not the one I was editing, the code as it is in the original question actually works. Again sorry, and thanks a ton for being willing to try and solve my problem. How should I divvy the points/ which solution would be best to accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to refactor this code into:

```
execSomeSqlStatement("UPDATE client_notes SET client_notes_duedate = NULL 
 WHERE client_notes_id=" & clientnotes_id)
```

Perhaps refactor a bit more to avoid the SQL injection vulnerability?

Comment: It now doesn't throw an error, however it doesn't overwrite the values in the DB, they stay the same after the update.

Comment: See comment under my question about the solution.

Comment: @Dale; hey no problem. Do you prefer the single statement (an UPDATE) instead of 3 statements (SELECT, field update, and rs.update)?